# Ardunio alarm clock without rtc projects error

Tags: c, arduino-uno

i am currently working in a ardunio alarm clock project without and rtc for school. I have a problem with my hour variable not increasing and my conditionals that checks it.

This code mostly works i can set time in hr and minutes but when the timer reaches 59 minutes the hour doesnt increase by 1. The second code that has been posted is the bit where the problem lies. Any tips/help would be appreciated.

```
 #include <Time.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_RGBLCDShield.h>
#include <utility/Adafruit_MCP23017.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
Adafruit_RGBLCDShield lcd = Adafruit_RGBLCDShield();


const int numofMenus = 4;
int currentMenu = 0;
String menu[4][2] = {{"Set hour", "hr"}, {"Set minutes", "min"}, {"Set alarm", "o"}, {"Current Time", "ha"}};
int parameters[24];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.noBlink();


}

void loop() {
  inputAction();

  if (currentMenu == 0)
  {
    printScreen();
  }
  if (currentMenu == 1)
  {
    printScreen();

  }
  if (currentMenu == 2)
  {
    printScreen();
  }
  if (currentMenu == 3)
  {

    int hr = parameters[0];
    int mn = minute(parameters[1]);
    int sec = second();
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Time: ");
    if (parameters[1] >= 0 && parameters[1] <= 59 && sec < 59) {
      parameters[0];
      printtime(parameters[0]);
    }
    else if (parameters[1] == 59 && second() == 59) {
      if (parameters[0]>=0 && parameters[0]<24){
        parameters[0];
      printtime(parameters[0]++);
      //delay(1000);}
      /*else if (parameters[0] == 24){
        parameters[0]= 0;
         printtime(parameters[0]);
        }*/
      }
    }
    lcd.print(":");
    if (sec >= 0 && sec < 59) {
      printtime(parameters[1]);
    }
    else if (sec == 59) {
      parameters[1];
      printtime(parameters[1]++);
      delay(1000);
    }
    lcd.print(":");
    printtime(sec);
    /* if (sec == 60) {
       mn+1;
       lcd.clear();
       lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
       lcd.print("Time: ");
       printtime(hr);
       lcd.print(":");
       printtime(mn);
       lcd.print(":");
       printtime(sec);
      }
      if (mn == 60) {
       hr+1;
       lcd.clear();
       lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
       lcd.print("Time: ");
       printtime(hr);
       lcd.print(":");
       printtime(mn);
       lcd.print(":");
       printtime(sec);
      }*/

    delay (100);

  }
}





void inputAction() {
  uint8_t buttons = lcd.readButtons();

  if (buttons & BUTTON_UP) {
    if (currentMenu == 0) {
      currentMenu = numofMenus - 1;
    } else {
      currentMenu--;
    }
  } else if (buttons & BUTTON_DOWN) {
    if (currentMenu == numofMenus - 1) {
      currentMenu = 0;
    } else {
      currentMenu++;
    }
  } else if (buttons & BUTTON_RIGHT) {
    parameters[currentMenu]++;
  } else if (buttons & BUTTON_LEFT) {
    parameters[currentMenu]--;
  }

}

void printScreen() {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print(menu[currentMenu][0]);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(parameters[currentMenu]);
  lcd.print(" ");
  lcd.print(menu[currentMenu][1]);
  delay(100);
}

void printtime(int data) {
  if (data >= 0 && data < 10) {
    lcd.print('0');
  }
  lcd.print(data);
}
```

Comment: To exlpain the code problem properly. in this part of the code i am trying to clear a condition in which it checks if the minute has reached 59 minutes and 59 second which then adds 1 to the hour. But instead what i get is that the hour just disappear and the minute increase to 60 instead of resetting back to zero. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.  This is litterally one of the last bit i have left to do on this project which i have to submit in 11 days.

Comment: Can you fix your code. It seems you have an extra curly bracket at the end. Better copy and paste it into the post again and make sure you format the code properly.

Comment: i have made sure the code posted before works now and no compiling errors.

Comment: I would suggest to make three variables, which hold your current h, m and s. If s, for example have to be increased by 1 and it's current value is 59, so reset it to 0 and add 1 to your m; the same for m and h. If you want to keep it simple, you may work with delays. But: The more delays, the more inaccurate the clock will work. Edit: Oh, and then you can print your time values to a display, to Serial or to a driver.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good strategy to throw all those delays in the code. If you want to work with an RTC, you need to be mindful of those delays as they will affect the functionality of your program. If you don't account for delay properly, they will accumulate as errors. An error of 100 msecs will be seen as `error in seconds` easily within days.

I did not go through your code because it is hard to understand. I propose you have a look at this code which should be placed in your `loop()` function:

```
  delay(100);
  parameters = parameters + 100;    

  long rtcSeconds = parameters / 1000;
  int seconds = (int) (rtcSeconds % 60);  // Range 0 . 59  units: Secs
  int minutes = (int)(((rtcSeconds - seconds) / 60) % 60);   // Range 0 . 59  units: Mins
  int hours =   (int) (((rtcSeconds -  minutes*60 - seconds) / (3600)) % 24);   // Range 0 . 23 units: Hrs
```

I am using your `parameters[0]` field to keep track of the time in your syste, in milliseconds units. The field increases every 100 msecs as you see. You can recover the different time values using a combination of the modulus (`%`) and division operations. Now, I know you need to increase the time in your program. To do so, it is easy:

- If you want to increase one second, do this: `parameters[0] += 1000;`
- If you want to increase one minute, do this: `parameters[0] += 1000 * 60;`
- If you want to increase one hour, do this: `parameters[0] += 1000 * 3600;`

Now, you might need to work with **long** variables as int have a limited range. You also need to watch for the time roll over when you change your time. If you are decreasing the time, you need to watch `pramaters[0]` doesn't become negative. In case it does, you need to add `3600 * 24 * 1000 msecs` to force it jump one day ahead (`3600 * 24` is one day in seconds). I hope you understand this is not a solution to your problem but an alternative approach using a little bit of a simpler code structure.

Comment: hello, in this project i am not allowed rtc. My code can set time but the increament on the hr and conditional check dont work. but i will try your solution and reply

Comment: hello, i tired your method. i realised thats the first thing i tried when solving the process. My problem is that following your method and i could not set time from the menu @kfrajer

Comment: What do you mean you cannot set the time from the menu? You mean, the menu that is part of your code?

Comment: Thanks for the help i used some of your suggestion and it worked